# What’s the meaning of ‘they don’t make them like that’?

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

(As an incredibly beautiful girl with silvery hair crossed the Hall, many boys gaped at her.)

> "I’m telling you, that's not a normal girl!" said Ron, leaning sideways so he could keep a clear view of her. "**They don’t make them like that** at Hogwarts!"
>
> "**They make them okay** at Hogwarts," said Harry without thinking. Cho happened to be sitting only a few places away from the girl with the silvery hair.
>
> (p252-253, Harry Potter 4, US edition)

**NB** – Hogwarts, the school of Ron and Harry, is having a lot of guests for Triwizard Tournament. **The beautiful girl** is one of the guests in a guest school. **Cho** is a pretty girl in Hogwarts. Harry likes her very much.

I’d like to know

- who ‘they’ are.
- who ‘them’ are.
- what ‘make’ means.

In other words, the whole sentence!
I’d be happy if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "they" is the same "they" as in "that's what they say".

It used to be a commonplace to say "they don't make them like that any more" -- "them" being cars or clothes or whatever, and "they" being whoever was in the business of manufacturing such things.  Greg Kihn had a #15 hit in 1981 with "[The Breakup Song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8ePSJ44Fiw)", known for its recurring lyric "They don't write 'em like that anymore", referring to songs.

Ron is making a play on words, implying girls at the school were being built in place, and the faculty, or the girls' parents, should be responsible for producing for silvery-haired Asian chicks of a particularly high quality.

Comment: – Thank you for the quick response. By the way, excuse me, but what is #15?

Comment: And, of course, they *could* build girls at Hogwarts, but it's probably against the school rules.

Comment: Anyway, I got it thanks to your good explanation. The recurring lyric is circling in my mind now.

Comment: I reckon what Ron was getting at, was that girls "nowadays" aren't as nice as that silver-haired girl he was looking at. He was stating that the girl was beautiful in an "oldie" type of way, but still beautiful.

Comment: @totoro -- #15 means that it was at one point fifteenth on the [Billboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billboard_Hot_100) chart.  @Ham -- the original phrase "make them like that any more" compares then with now, but I think Ron was comparing Hogwarts with wherever the girl was from.